# Want to know how to use trunc() and to_date()

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to match dates with this. 
trunc(day,'DD')>= trunc('01-JAN-10','DD') what is wrong with this?

'day' is "10-JAN-10"

Comment: Are you using Oracle ?

Comment: Do you have a problem with your syntax?  What is the full query?

Comment: Hi, I want the min date set to the date '01-JAN-10'.without the date.

Comment: without the day.  Is this right? trunc(day,'DD')>= trunc(to_date('01-JAN-10','DD'),'DD-MON-YY')

Comment: trunc(day, 'DD')>=trunc(to_date('01-JAN-10','DD-MON-YY'),'DD') this works. I think i got it.Thanks guys

Comment: If that's your actual syntax, you can just use `to_date('01-JAN-10','DD-MON-YY')`.  The trunc() does nothing since the literal string has no time component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in finding all the records whose "day" field is greater than 01-JAN-10 then you can use the following where clause. This will also use the index on the "day" field if there is any:

```
where day >= to_date('2010/01/01','YYYY/MM/DD')
```